# How to produce markup from a custom views field (FieldPluginBase based) render method in D8?

Tags: views, theming, entities

I've created a custom views field following the excelent [Creating a custom Views field in Drupal 8](https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-field-drupal-8) guide. The `render` method returns the desired output, except that it's being sanitized somewhere down the line and thus the html markup comes out as plain text on the page.

I'd rather put the html markup into the theme, but there doesn't seem to be such thing as

views-view-field-`<fieldname>`.html.twig

in Drupal8 ?

Comment: yes, such a template name suggestion for field names does exist: `views-view-field--field-name.html.twig`, problem is only, that twig debug is not able to display it

Comment: Can you show us your render() method?

Answer (score 3):

I can output HTML using my render method. Take a look:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render(ResultRow $values) {

    $field_abnormal_category = $this->view->field['field_abnormal_category']->original_value->__toString();

    if($field_abnormal_category == 'No') {
      $field_category_image = $this->view->field['field_category_image']->original_value->__toString();
    }
    else {
      $field_category_image = '';
    }

    return [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => $field_category_image
    ];

  }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works on Drupal 9 too.